# How to parse through multiple body tags using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse through a websites registration page which is basically a pop up. When the pop up is opened The `<body>` changes to `<body class= modal-open>`. I want to parse through the  `<body class= modal-open>`. Please help. I have tried the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get("some site")
content = driver.page_source
while(loaded):
            state = driver.execute_script('return document.readyState')
            if state == 'complete':
                loaded = False #this is to stop the loop if the page completely loads with its js changes
                html2 = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, "lxml")
                body = soup.find_all('body', attrs={'class':['modal-open']})
                print(body)
```

Comment: Can you provide the url?